# How to make code reuse possible in payment gateway microservice

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, payment-gateway

The problem I am solving is wanting to reuse code between different payment gateways in microservice. Suppose I want to have a makePayment() method in my controller. Adding some rough way on how the code might look:

**Controller**:

```
Response makePayment(@RequestBody request){
    if(request.gateway == PAYU){
       // call PayU service
    }
    else if(request.gateway == Paypal){

    }
}
```

**Service**

```
Entity payuservice(request){
   // request.method ??
}
```

**Entity**

```
class Entity {
  String mode; // CC,DC, Wallet
  String status;
  ...
}
```

*Repository*

```
interface PayuRepository {

}
```

So my questions combined would be,

1. I want to reuse code across different payment gateways. What can I do here when I have the gateway name in the request along with payment details from the form?
2. Do I need to consider different methods on the backend? The entity would only have a different values for different methods? For e.g UPI would have one extra field
   3)Do I need different repositories for different gateways or different tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something nice with a mix of the Adapter and the Strategy design patterns. The Strategy would determine what gateway-specific code to run, and the Adapter would translate the payment request to the gateway model (and vice-versa).

Comment: How would I tie this in a DI container context using Spring Boot?